# Clean text from CodeMirror in Selenium

Tags: selenium, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ and Slenium for testing, however, I have a CodeMirror that I want to edit the information for, I am trying to delete said information with Keys.chord (Keys.CONTROL, "a"), but it seems that the keys.chord it doesn't work. When I say it doesn't work, I mean it doesn't select all the information inside the CodeMirror element.

Could you give me some help?

This is the code I use:

```
public void EditData(String DataList) throws Exception {
        WaitForElementVisible(By.id(Web.Edit_Rule_Button_id));
        click(By.id(Web.Edit_Rule_Button_id));

        WaitForElementPresence(By.xpath(Web.edit_input_xpath));
        moveToElement(By.xpath(Web.edit_input_xpath));
        click(By.xpath(Web.edit_input_xpath));
        Actions actions = new Actions(getDriverProvider().get());

        actions.moveToElement(findElement(By.xpath(Web.edit_input_xpath))).click()
                .sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a") + Keys.BACK_SPACE).perform();
        System.out.println("Data cleared");

        actions.moveToElement(findElement(By.xpath(Web.Edit_input_xpath))).click()
                .sendKeys(DataList).perform();
        System.out.println("Data updated");

        click(By.id(Web.SaveButton_id));
        WaitForElementPresence(By.id(Web.ConfirmSaveButton_id));
        click(By.id(Web.ConfirmSaveButton_id));

        WaitUntilInvisible(By.id(Web.ConfirmSaveButton_id),2);
        WaitForElementVisible(By.xpath(Web.SavedContent_xpath));
        System.out.println("Data Updated");
    }
```

In this xpath I have the codemirror
Web.edit_input_xpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I was able to solve it as follows, I added keyboard actions to it to be able to solve my problem

```
actions.moveToElement(findElement(By.xpath(Web.edit_input_xpath))).click()
                .sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a") + Keys.BACK_SPACE).perform();
actions.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL);
        actions.sendKeys("a");
        actions.keyUp(Keys.CONTROL);
        actions.perform();
        actions.moveToElement(findElement(By.xpath(Web.edit_input_xpath))).sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE).perform()
        System.out.println("Data cleared");
```